# Single ObservableAsPropertyHelper with multiple ReactiveCommand IsExecuting

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

From the sample [here](https://reactiveui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/ReactiveUI-101/), I'm trying to change the `_SpinnerVisibility` to multiple reactivecommand objects. So below snippet shows what I did..

```
public ReactiveCommand<object> ExecuteSearch { get; protected set; }

public ReactiveCommand<List<string>> OtherOperation { get; protected set; }

public AppViewModel(ReactiveCommand<object> testExecuteSearchCommand = null, IObservable<List<FlickrPhoto>> testSearchResults = null)
{

_SpinnerVisibility = OtherOperation.IsExecuting.Select(x=> x? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed)                
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.SpinnerVisibility, Visibility.Hidden);
_SpinnerVisibility = ExecuteSearch.IsExecuting.Select(x=> x? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed)                
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.SpinnerVisibility, Visibility.Hidden);
}
```

Here I was setting the visibility based on multiple reactive commands. But always the last registered command will trigger the visibility. Is there a way to change the visibility based on both the reactive commands `ExecuteSearch, OtherOperation`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to merge both IsExecuting observables into one.

If your commands are mutually exclusive (that is they can't execute at the same time), this should work:

```
_SpinnerVisibility = new IReactiveCommand[] { ExecuteSearch, OtherOperation }
    .Select(cmd => cmd.IsExecuting)
    .Merge()
    .Select(x=> x? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed)                
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.SpinnerVisibility, Visibility.Hidden);
```

If they can be, then it'll be more like:

```
_SpinnerVisibility = new IReactiveCommand[] { ExecuteSearch, OtherOperation }
    .Select(cmd => cmd.IsExecuting)
    .CombineLatest()
    .Select(x => x.Any() ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible)                
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.SpinnerVisibility, Visibility.Hidden);
```

Both will work with any number of commands.

Comment: This seems to be working for ReactiveCommands of similar type. But what should be the case for Reactive commands of different type. Please see the edit above.

Comment: edited my answer, `IReactiveCommand` is a common interface that you can use

Comment: not working.. again the same. It is acting on OtherOperation only.

Comment: Did you try the Merge or CombineLatest approach ? Maybe you can link/paste (e.g. gist) your updated code ? the commands listed in the array will be all considered, so if a command is listed there, it'll work.